# Upgraded to Magento 2.4.5-p1. Our SKUs are 13 digits. Search won't return anything unless SKU length is 9 or less. Any ideas?

Tags: catalogsearch, sku, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.5p1, sku-length

Search won't return anything unless SKU length is 9 or less. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

**Can you check this configuration?**

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog
> Search -> Minimal Query Length

[image]

Comment: It is set to 1.

Comment: Edit, It actually is 10 digits max. Not 9.